# Character encoding in routes file, scandic letters not recognised in request URL

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Scandic letters (like äöå) in url e.g. `localhost:9000/ääliöurli` are not recognized, routing is not going where wanted.

Routes file:

`GET /ääliöurli  controllers.Application.aalio()`

Question is; can i put into some config file or run parameter the selection of UTF-8 character encoding that affects more than just views?

Or is the there a simple way to fix this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions in that situation:

First is definitely uncomfortable, it's placing UTF encoded routes...

```
GET /%C3%A4%C3%A4li%C3%B6urli
```

Second is writing `catch-all` route at the end of your routes config and handling routes ie. with DB support. In Play 2.0 catch-all route it's route described as [`Dynamic parts spanning several /`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaRouting)

I'm using the second approach in few places with success, anyway at least for the first implementation you'll probably need to reserve few hours for planning and coding the solution.

Comment: The first UTF encoded route is a solution good enough now, even not a pretty one :) but seem to do the trick. Now having only a couple of static routes with scandics.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug, there is a wip pull-request for that: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/796